# How can I use bluetooth controller in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have bluetooth controller in picture. How do I use joystick and other 6 button on my android game? I can acces only escape button on controller with (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))

[bluetooth controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUKPe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably debug this by doing something like:

```
if(Input.anyKeyDown)
    Debug.Log(Input.inputString);
```

in your update-function to see what buttons are pressed.

[Documentation for Input.inputString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-inputString.html)

You may also find some clues [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1164979/how-do-i-use-android-bluetooth-controller-in-unity.html)

There's also [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/17669/setting-up-game-pad.html) for setting up controllers.

Comment: I can not find the names of Key commands when I connect controller it is opening mice on screen.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you're saying... You wish to know the names of the keys on the bluetooth device, I got that from the original question - did my debug solution not print out the name of the keys pressed? It should allow you to click any button and tell you in the debug console the name of the key pressed.

Comment: your answer helpful but not work on android device because bluetooth device work with joystick and buttons (I attach Input.inputString to my UI.text) when I pressed the buttons nothing show 2 buttons control volume other one click and escape. Have you got a same bluetooth device?

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

bluetooth controller like a key board.
Joystick is like arrow key (Horizontal,Vertical)
button in controller is like (Left/Right ctrl, Left/Right alt, space)
change input type for joystick in ProjectSetting> Input> Horizontal/Vertical>Type to Joystick axis
I'm tried it out and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).